# How can i refresh my primary key column?

Tags: java, sql, database, db2, hibernate-annotations

Till recent time i was using hibernate `@Entity` **annotation** to map to database tables.All the primary keys are annotated with **@GeneratedValue**`(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

I got a scenario where i need to create new schema + migrate data from old schema into new schema.(with few column changes like drop, length and type)

After successful migration of data to new schema tables when i try to insert data using Application its throwing an exception

```
[ERROR] util.JDBCExceptionReporter DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=1; _NewSchema_._TableName_ , DRIVER=3.51.90
```

I believe that application is trying to insert rows again with Primary key value starting from 1 because same application is working fine with empty tables.

I want data rows to be inserted with its primary key value as highest value of existing rows primary key .

Any help will be thank full :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct, here is my solution, execute the following SQL to give the ID column a specified start position, then your application will work fine.

```
alter table TABLE_NAME alter column ID set GENERATED BY DEFAULT RESTART WITH 10000;
```

Hope to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that by altering the table. Alter the table and set starting index for identity column in `DB2`.

Suppose maximum rows for `TBALE_A` is `50` and name of identity column is `TABLE_ID`

```
ALTER TABLE TBALE_A ALTER COLUMN TABLE_ID
   RESTART WITH 51
```

Comment: If you got the answer then accept the answer by clicking accept arrow.

Answer (score 0):

In case of generation type , IDENTITY, you should look for identity column to be auto incemental. 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) required primary key column to be auto incremental.